# Stripe space between integer and alphabet

Tags: php, regex

I wish to turn this string:
"25 Horse Power" to "25Horse Power"

And respectively
"Foo bar 25 stack 1 overflow" to "Foo bar 25stack 1overflow"

Is there an efficient way of doing this in regex?

Comment: Please explain why you are removing the space after `25` in the first example but before `25` in the second example.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that was my mistake. *edited*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookarounds regex:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\h+(?=[a-zA-Z])/', '', $input);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN2rB2/1)

```
(?<=\d)       # assert that previous char is a digit
\h+           # match 1 or more horizontal space
(?=[a-zA-Z])  # assert that next char in an English letter
```

Comment: Thank you especially for the explanation. Answer cannot be cleaner than this.